# Using telnet and "Duration" header to do the tests

Tags: apache-2.2

I have create a custom response header called "Duration" that records the time taken to generate the response. Allow this header to be returned only when the request header "Client" with the value of "Get-Duration" is supplied.

which is:
SetEnvIf Client ^Get-Duration$ SET_DURATION 
Header set X-Duration %D env=SET_DURATION

How can I use telnet and "Duration" header to test some file. Should I use ab benchmarking or httperf testing or is there any tests method?

Answer (score 1):

Send this in your telnet session:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Client: Get-Duration
```

If everything's working properly you'll get the X-Duration response header back.